# How do I get a value from append child by element name?

Tags: jquery

I got this html:

```
<div id="mydiv" name="mydiv" class="mydiv"></div>
```

And I'm appeding:

```
$(".mydiv").append("<div><p><textarea id='myTextarea' name='myTextarea'></textarea><input type='button' class='sendReply btn btn-default' value='my button'></input></p></div>");
```

Now I want to get the value from my textarea element by its name... I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.sendReply', function () {
    alert($("#mydiv").children("#myTextarea").val());
});
```

What goes wrong?

Comment: Are you appending `textarea` multiple times?

Comment: `alert($("#mydiv").find("#myTextarea").val());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code didn't worked as `.children()` is being used which only targets immediate child's.

As you have specified ID attribute, you can directly access using it

```
console.log($("#myTextarea").val());
```

---

If you are appending multiple times, then use DOM travesal methods to target the elements. As duplicate IDs will render HTML invalid.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.sendReply', function() {
  console.log($(this).prev("textarea").val());
});

$(".mydiv").append("<div><p><textarea id='myTextarea' name='myTextarea'></textarea><input type='button' class='sendReply btn btn-default' value='my button'></input></p></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" name="mydiv" class="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your `textarea` a specific `ID` anyway, you don't need to refer to the div's `children`. You can get its value by selecting it using its `ID`:

Here's a working snippet:

```js
$(".mydiv").append("<div><p><textarea id='myTextarea' name='myTextarea'></textarea><input type='button' class='sendReply btn btn-default' value='my button'></input></p></div>");

jQuery(document).on('click','.sendReply', function () {
    alert($("#myTextarea").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" name="mydiv" class="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(".mydiv").append("<div><p><textarea id='myTextarea' name='myTextarea'></textarea><input type='button' class='sendReply btn btn-default' value='my button'></input></p></div>");

jQuery(document).on('click','.sendReply', function () {
    alert($("#mydiv").find("#myTextarea").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" name="mydiv" class="mydiv"></div>
```

It should be `alert($("#mydiv").find("#myTextarea").val());` instead of `alert($("#mydiv").children("#myTextarea").val());`

For traversing use `.find` method rather than `.children`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

`children()` can only give you just child attribute, you can use `find()` method if you have not aware level of child attribute instead of `children()`

```
alert($("#mydiv").find("#myTextarea").val());
```

OR

it can access directly

```
alert($("#myTextarea").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with id selector of textarea. It is working.

```js
$(".mydiv").append("<div><p><textarea id='myTextarea' name='myTextarea'></textarea><input type='button' class='sendReply btn btn-default' value='my button'></input></p></div>");
jQuery(document).on('click','.sendReply', function () { alert($("#myTextarea").val());
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" name="mydiv" class="mydiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```